# Creating a User Interface in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to create just a simple user interface with buttons, input and output in ruby. I have done it before in Java but I can't find anything like it in ruby. I was wondering if there is a standard library in ruby for GUI or if I need some sort of gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tk is the Standard GUI

While there are certainly other GUI toolkits like [FXRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/) and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) is the standard that is included in the [Ruby Standard Library.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/tk/rdoc/)